# How To Hide Action Bar And/Or TabLayout

Tags: java, android

I have several activities in my android app which consist of Action Bar followed by TabLayout. TabLayout contains ViewPager which further has RecyclerView. Here's the complete xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
tools:context="com.parassidhu.cdlumaths.quePap">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout1"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/adID" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The app looks like this:

[image]

Now what I would like to do is whenever user scrolls through RecyclerView, at least Action Bar should become hidden. How to hide Action Bar + Tab Layout both? I don't want any external libraries since they involve reconstructing layout. Is there any possible way? Thanks!

Comment: tabLayout.setVisabelity(View.GONE);

Comment: Can you explain where to add this code?

Comment: just after initializing the tablayout.

Comment: @HAXM please explain more